# Erro na copilagem do IONIC 4

Tags: ionic4

Peguei uma pasta de um projeto,feito no IONIC 4,do meu amigo no GITHUB, e na hora de abrir o projeto da erro.Alguém poderia me ajudar?

[image: Print do erro]

Answer (score 0):

Está bastante difícil de ver essa imagem que você mandou mas o que conseguir ler foi que o ionic não está conseguindo encontrar um pacote. Tenta remover os módulos e reinstala-los novamente